# Saving the login to the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

please tell me how to save the input of the game. I mean that the player was authorized (entered a password and nickname), passed several levels and exited. How do I make sure that next time he does not log in again, but immediately goes to the levels menu?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) - it is a good mechanics to save your global data. For an example, you want to save player' login:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Login", "AvgustKuk");
// later get this value:
var login = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Login");
```

You can serialize your data and store it as you want.

Comment: And if I have a database connected, will it break anything?)

Comment: @AvgustKuk it depends on your code :) PlayerPrefs are writing to the user device locally, not to your database. Anyways, without single string of code i can't say what will be with your anything :)